# ForEach statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am trying to run the below command. It should get all the user mail boxes from the exchange server and run the script. But when I run it only does for the first mail box and stops. I want the script to run for each mailbox. Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

```
$mailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -resultsize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox
Foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){
    .\graph-PopulateContactsFromCSV.ps1 -Mailbox $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID -CSVPath $csvPath
}
```

Comment: You are calling a secondary script without showing or saying what it is doing. Based on what you posted, I cannot see a reason for that second script. Spend a bit more time reading up on PowerShell Loops.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Finally I was able to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

Try this (refactor as needed):

```
Get-EXOMailbox -resultsize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox | 
ForEach-Object {.\graph-PopulateContactsFromCSV.ps1 -Mailbox $PSItem.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID -CSVPath $csvPath}
```

I don't to have ADDS handy, but doing this for local users:

```
Get-LocalUser -Name '*' | 
ForEach-Object {$PSitem.Name}
# Results
<#
Admi..
Da..
Def..
Guest
L..
WDAGUtilityAccount
#>
```